# Auctex not compiling on C-c C-c, "TeX-master-file-ask: Master file already set"

Tags: compiling, emacs, auctex

I recently started using Emacs/Auctex on windows 10. I am trying to compile a latex document using the command C-c C-c and it does not compile and instead just reports "TeX-master-file-ask: Master file already set" in the mini buffer. Even it says same thing for C-c C-a or just choosing from GUI Command/ Latex. How can I fix this?

If I delete this end part,

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

and press C-c C-c then it asks for master and then compiles.

Below are the modifications to the init file I have made,

```
(setq-default ispell-program-name "C:/Aspell/bin/aspell.exe")

(setq text-mode-hook '(lambda() (flyspell-mode t) ))

(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)

;; Turn on RefTeX in AUCTeX

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook' turn-on-reftex)

;; Activate nice interface between RefTeX and AUCTeX

(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is due to an outdated installation

Comment: I don't get it. Outdated installation? I see no version number or anything. In fact, I have the same problem after updating my Tex Live installation.

Comment: Agreed. Same here!

Answer (score 1):

I did a uninstall, followed by restart and install again from scratch. It works now. I can compile again without issues.